# CSS selectors question

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm not sure if what I'm looking for is called selectors - so let's hope people will understand my question...

I have (let's say) something like this:

```
<div id="mainwrapper" class="default">
 <div class="boxone"></div>
 <div class="boxtwo"></div>
 ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.default {width: 100%; background-color: #fff;}
.boxone {width: 50%; background: #f00;}
.boxtwo {width: 50%; background: #0f0;}
```

What I need to do is to add something like this to my CSS (changing mainwrapper's className to "dark" also changes all it's child elements):

```
.dark {background: #000;}
.dark > .boxone {background: #333;}
.dark > .boxone {background: #666;}
```

My second CSS is (probably) wrong, but I guess it's done like that... but how? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.dark .boxone {background: #333;}
.dark .boxtwo {background: #666;}
```

Should work. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PURLw/1/

Answer (score 2):

Your css will work in the second case. http://jsfiddle.net/8VZZV/

This happens because the second selectors has bigger [selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) than first.

Read an article about this [here](http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/).

The greater-than sign [`>`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector) is used to select immediate children, but internet explorer supports it by version 8. So I suggest to use `.dark .boxone {background: #333;}`

Also fix the second rule in your css to `.dark > .boxtwo {background: #666;}`

Answer (score 1):

```
.default {width: 100%; background-color: #fff;}
.default .boxone {width: 50%; background-color: #f00;}
.default .boxtwo {width: 50%; background-color: #0f0;}

.dark {width: 100%; background-color: #000;}
.dark .boxone {width: 50%; background-color: #666;}
.dark .boxtwo {width: 50%; background-color: #666;}
```

OR if you want to have `class="default dark"`

```
.default.dark {background-color: #000;}
.default.dark .boxone {background-color: #666;}
.default.dark .boxtwo {background-color: #666;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example will work, but using `>` means only direct children of `.dark` will be selected. If you want to select grandchildren (and further children) as well, just get rid of the `>` character:

Select direct child with class `.boxone`:

```
.dark > .boxone {background: #666;}
```

Select any child with class `.boxone`:

```
.dark .boxone {background: #666;}
```